# Fundamental group of cylinder -triangulation method

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, trees, fundamental-groups

Is this correct?
[image: cylinder]
Can we conclude that the fundamental group is trivial since there are no remaining generators on 1-simplices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The leftmost and rightmost top vertices are actually the same point on the cylinder, so your yellow "tree" actually contains a cycle.

(Using 0, 1, 2, 3 to refer to the horizontal lines top to bottom and a, b, c, d to refer to the vertical ones from left to right, the cycle I mean is a0, b0, b1, b2, b3, c3, c2, c1, c0, d0=a0.)